# How to enable cycle style / topography in android's SDK?

Tags: android, skmaps, skobbler-maps

I'm trying to include topographic info using Skobbler's Android SDK, but the Cycle map style is not available as it is in the online version [image: Sample image]

Included styles in the SKMaps assets are day, grayscale, night and outdoor.

My main goal is to include the elevation contours as in the sample above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no such style on mobile - the cycle map style used on web is only a raster style and has no "vector equivalent"

Comment: Is there any possibility to provide such in the near feature?

Comment: This is not planned in the next 6 months